# Trying to listObjects from AWS S3 using anonymous credentials but it is still checking in ~/.aws/credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Here is the code that I am using to `listSummaries` of objects (it's 99% the same from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html).

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());  

    System.out.println("bucketname = " + bucketName + "key =" + key);


    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(key);
    List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = new ArrayList<S3ObjectSummary>();

    ObjectListing objectListing;

    do {
        line 147 >>> objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            summaries.add(objectSummary);
        }
        listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
    } while (objectListing.isTruncated());
```

Here is where it says that you can use anonymous credentials to access publicly accessible buckets (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingAcctOrUserCredJava.html) I am sure that the bucket I am accessing is open-sourced. I am getting the following error message and I have no idea why that is happening:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS credential profiles file not found in the given path: /home/xxx/.aws/credentials
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.ProfilesConfigFileLoader.loadProfiles(ProfilesConfigFileLoader.java:45)
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.loadProfiles(ProfilesConfigFile.java:194)
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:119)
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:93)
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:149)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3589)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3548)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:647)
at xxx.xxx.xxx.LocalInterface.ListBucket(LocalInterface.java:147)
```

Answer (score 6):

I figured out my own answer. I was not using anonymous credentials. Here's how to use them:

```
AWSCredentials creds = new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(creds);
```

Hope this helps someone.